# How to see your allies' resources in Starcraft II team games?

Tags: starcraft-2

Yesterday I was playing some team games and wanted to ask my teammates for gas. Before asking I wanted to check what their resources look like. But I couldn't find a way to do it.

I tried to open the resources trading menu and clicking on my allies buildings. Is there a command for that or a setting? How to do it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Ask in the (voice) chat or just request the resources.